# Two Navigation Bar are showing

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

its shows two navigationBarControllers!

Top blue and below default NavigationBar.

[image]

```
var rootVC = CustomNavigationController()
    let tabbarViewController  = UIStoryboard(name: AppStoryboard.dashboard.rawValue, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController
    rootVC = CustomNavigationController.init(rootViewController: tabbarViewController)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = rootVC
```

Comment: "rootVC.isNavigationBarHidden = true" add this line to hide default navigation bar

Answer (score 0):

If you already have navigation controller before Tabbar, you dont need to create another navigation controller for each of viewController inside that Tabbar